# Is there a way to use a SQL Server 2000 database in SSIS 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, ssis, sql-server-2012

I just got my first chance to install SQL Server 2012 on a test machine.  I also installed all of the management and Visual Studios components.  I created a copy of one of my SSIS 2008 packages and converted it to 2012.  The conversion worked jsut fine, but I'm now getting an error stating that **connections to SQL Server 2000 and earlier versions are no longer supported**.

Is there a workaround for this?  Is there another way to create a connection to a 2000 database?  We're not currently in a place to move this database off of 2000.

The connection is currently set up as an OLE DB connection for a couple of data sources.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet to post comments, so I guess I'll have to post here: Could you maybe create an ODBC DSN to the server / database and use that instead of OLE DB?

Comment: What connection manager (ole, odbc, ado) are you using to talk to the SQL 2000 instance? Is it being used as a source, destination, lookup, something-else?

Comment: @billinkc added info

Comment: Well you could upgrade your SQL Server to an instance. I don't mean to sound callus but your server will be able to buy cigarettes in a few years.

Comment: @Zane Ehh, we've finally gotten rid of it.  Now to update all the things.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 (the one that ships with SQL Server 2012) does not support SQL Server 2000. All you have to do is change the data source to use a .Net Provider (SqlClient Data Provider) instead of the Native OLE DB provider. The .Net Provider probably doesn't perform quite as well as the Native OLE DB but it was definitely a lot less work that having to build a bunch of new ETLs to stage the data and a lot less risky too.